# Find out what's running wget on my server

Tags: unix, logging, munin, wget

In my access.log I see requests coming from 127.0.0.1 and retrieving server's "/" and then all of graphics and CSS referenced in it. This happens regularly, every 5 minutes.

I want to find out what, why and how runs wget like this.

I changed "referer" in `/etc/wgetrc` to verify it's local wget executable making these calls, it is.
Couldn't find anything suspicious in crontab.
The server is running munin-node. Could a munin plugin be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, OK, it's Munin's `http_loadtime` plugin. 
It's a plugin to graph httpresponse time of a specific page.
Defaults to using wget and grabbing "http://localhost/". Mystery solved :-)

Comment: `atop`'s service mode can help answer "what was running back during that ten minute slice" questions.